# Recommended way to run another program from within a Python script

Tags: python, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python)

I'm writing a Python script on a windows machine. I need to launch another application "OtherApp.exe". What is the most suitable way to do so?

Till now I've been looking at `os.system()` or `os.execl()` and they don't quite look appropriate (I don't even know if the latter will work in windows at all).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. Wish I could close it. Did vote though.

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way is to use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). All other ways (like `os.system()` or `exec`) are brittle, unsecure and have subtle side effects that you should not need to care about. subprocess replaces all of them.

Answer (score -1):

*Note that this answer is specific to python versions 2.x which I am locked to due to an embedded system.  I am only leaving it for historical reasons just in case.*

One of the things the subprocess offers is a method to catch the output of a command, for example using [popen] on a windows machine

```
import os
os.popen('dir').read()
```

will yield

' Volume in drive C has no label.\n Volume Serial Number is 54CD-5392\n\n Directory of C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\n\n[.]              [..]             dde.pyd          license.txt\nPythonwin.exe    [pywin]          scintilla.dll    tmp.txt\nwin32ui.pyd      win32uiole.pyd   \n               7 File(s)        984,178 bytes\n               3 Dir(s)  30,539,644,928 bytes free\n'

Which can then be parsed or manipulated any way you want.

Comment: the subprocess module has replaced os.popen in newer version of Python.  That is the recommended way to handle this. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html